# CSS Selector and HTML

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Below is my CSS and HTML code.

Given CSS selector is not applied when there is a `hidden` field between `INPUT` and `SPAN` tags

**CSS**

```
input[type="checkbox"] + .lbl:before {
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
```

**CSS Working**

```
<label>
<input name="SMS" type="checkbox" />
<span class="lbl"> choice 2</span>
</label>
```

**CSS Not Applied**

```
<label>
<input name="SMS" type="checkbox" />
<input type="hidden" value="false" name="SMS">
<span class="lbl"> choice 2</span>
</label>
```

How can I change/add new CSS selector change to support both cases?

**Note:** The `Hidden` field was automatically generated by `ASP.Net MVC` framework and we dont have a control to place it in other place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [general sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators) `~` if you're trying to style a sibling that is not necessarily *immediately* following another element.

So in your case

```
input[type="checkbox"] ~ .lbl:before {
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
```

Would work in both scenarios

http://jsfiddle.net/Hx8ZG/

Answer (score 3):

The `+` indicates that the element is placed immediately after the checkbox.

You could change it to `>` which indicates a parent.

```
input[type="checkbox"] > .lbl:before {
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TkamX/

Note: I have added a new `div` and used that as the parent element.

```
div > .lbl {
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
```

You can also use a single selector by giving your `span` an ID and then select based on that.

Comment: @Adrift - yes that's why I put it as a div in my example.  I was going to state that having a span inside an input is bad practice etc.  You can also use other selectors or an ID.

Answer (score 1):

If the only possible issue here is a hidden input field between the checkbox and the span, then you should be able to reference that in your selector:

```
input[type="checkbox"] + input[type="hidden"] + .lbl:before {
    ....
}
```

Alternatively, if the hidden field may or may not be there, then you'll need to allow for both options:

```
input[type="checkbox"] + .lbl:before, input[type="checkbox"] + input[type="hidden"] + .lbl:before {
    ....
}
```

If there could be more elements between the two, and you don't know what they could be, then you'll need to swap your `+` selector for a `~` selector, which selects any sibling rather than the adjacent one.

```
input[type="checkbox"] ~ .lbl:before {
    ....
}
```

This option might be the simplest, but does have the caveat that it might select things which wouldn't have been selected by your original `+` selector.

Hope that helps.